# How uppercase words with space and "-" between

Tags: php, uppercase

I would like to change a string with

```
hello teSt woRld hEllo-woRld
```

to

```
Hello Test World Hello-World
```

I did something, that observes only spaces between the words.
But I need it for spaces and "-" between. Can someone tell me how to achieve it ?

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ( $words as $key=>$value ) {
  $new .= mb_strtoupper( mb_substr( mb_strtolower( $value) , 0, 1, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8' ) . 
          mb_substr(mb_strtolower( $value ), 1, null, 'UTF-8') . ' ';
}
```

Comment: `echo ucwords( strtolower( $str) );` Then all you have to code for is the words that follow a hyphen

Comment: Thanks but need UTF-8 support (forgot to mention), as far as i know this wont work with ucwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try something like this :

```php
$string = "hello teSt woRld hEllo-woRld";
echo ucwords(strtolower($string), " -");
```

The second parameter of the `ucwords` function is the word delimiter. In this case, words are separated with either a space or a hyphen.

The result will be :

```
Hello Test World Hello-World
```

If you are concerned about keeping the UTF-8 format, you should consider using the `mb_convert_case` function like the example below :

```php
$str = "mary had a Little lamb and she loved it so";
$str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
echo $str; // Display: Mary Had A Little Lamb And She Loved It So
```

Comment: Thank you, solution 2 fits my needs. I will change it a bit to cut off hyphens that are in first or last position. Great!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with a regex

```
$str = 'hello teSt woRld hEllo-woRld';
$str = strtolower($str);

$line = preg_replace_callback(
    '(^\w|\s\w|\-\w)',
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    },
    $str
);
echo $line;
```